# Design rule engine for dataframes avoiding if-else ladder in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I want to add one column("`new_col`"). in a dataframe based on different rules which is computed from existing columns. The rules are complex and sometimes computed based on 4-5 columns of the dataframe. Pls refer to below snippet:

```
old dataframe = df(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)

new dataframe = old_dataframe.withcolums("new_col", myudf(col(A),col(B),col(C),col(D),col(E)))

entries in col(new_col) is computed as following:

def myudf(A,B,C,D,E): String = {
    if (A=="something") {
          if (B="something") {
            return val1
          } else {
            if (C>"something" || D<"something") {
             return val2
            }
            else {
              return func(E)
            }
          }
        } else {
         return val3
        }
      }
}
```

Currently, I have written the UDF which takes all the required column and return the value of new column to be added. But the problem is that udf function has become quite complex due to more rules and has become if-else ladder. I want to avoid it and am thinking of refactoring if possible. I also looked at other answers for avoiding if-else ladder but for this dataframe, none of the solutions are discussed.

Can anyone suggest if there is some neat way to write such rules for dataframes in scala?

Comment: too broad, nobody is going to answer that - at least provide a snippet as it all depends on use case

Comment: @bottaio added now. let me know if it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try pattern matching? Is way more clear than using if and elses

```
   (A,B, C, D) match {
    case ("something", "something", _, _)=> val1
    case ("something", _, cValue, dValue) if cValue > "something" || dValue <"something" => val2
    case ("something", _, _, _ ) => func(E)
    case _ => val3
  }
```

Comment: I think it will work for my use case. There are functions also in my usecase but looking https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html, it also supports functions instead of string. Will look into it for more details.